# Embedded HTML 5 video is stored in the cache but is not displayed on iPad 2

Tags: ipad, html, caching, video, offline

I am creating an offline webapp for the iPad 2, which includes video content. When the page first loads, the video displays fine. But when I reload the page, the video's play button becomes broken.

I've gone into Settings > Safari > Advanced > Website Data and, sure enough, the video is in the cache... So the problem seems to be that it is not being retrieved from the cache.

My HTML code snippet:

```
    <html manifest="cache.manifest">
    ...
        <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
            <source src="videos/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
```

My cache.manifest snippet:

```
    CACHE MANIFEST
    # Updated 2012-08-22 19:49:00
    index.php
    ...
    videos/movie.mp4
```

For good measure, my .htaccess snippet:

```
    AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This problem also happens (predictably) when I go into airplane/offline mode. The video size is 311KB. My iPad is running iOS 5.1.1.

Answer (score 4):

This unfortunately isn't an answer but after now 20 hours continuous searching and testing to resolve the exact same problem i can tell you where i am now.

This appears to be an ipad iOS specific problem where no matter what size the video / sound file is it will not draw on the cached files although they clearly are cached and on first load it plays the file OK.

I have tried making the smallest video possible.
I have looked at wrapping in a native app but that's not an option for delivery reasons.
I have tried forcing a reload of the video .src on page load using javascript.
I have tried all possible variations of the manifest file.
Looked at all the Apple developer docs i can stomach.

After reading hundreds of posts, that never actually complete, i think the answer, other than getting the client to buy Android tablets, is to use the local database to store the video in binary form to be retrieved when needed by the app. Unfortunately i am still searching for examples of this and as yet cant find any with any detail. Local saving of text / numerical data isn't a problem. I just dont know if its possible to store the raw file data and retrieve it in a local database.

Sorry its not what you were after but hope it helps point you in less directions.

An update but not much progress. I decided to use base64 ecoded mp4 and paste the text in a simple xml file. My app would read this xml video data and by using in the video tag SRC. This was about a 4MB string.

```
SRC="data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAA /...../ AA"
```

This worked fine in Chrome. When i used it on the Ipad the good points are that i didnt ever get the play button crossed out and it tried to play then flashed a message it could not complete this operation.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply - at least I know I'm not alone!

I have tried converting the video into Base64, then saving the Base64 data in the cache (with a .php extension) but that didn't work. I've also tried creating the video element with JavaScript, but that didn't work either on iPad.

Comment: I've also tried using the Base64 data as the value of the src attribute, but no joy there for iPad. I'm going to take a look at the database suggestion also...

Comment: Does anyone know if this problem would be overcome if I used PhoneGap to wrap the webapp as a native app?

Comment: I have looked at this but for me its not an option so didn't try it. I would like to think it would work though as you wont be caching the files using the manifest they will be inside the app. I will post results of my local database efforts when complete and hopefully working.

Comment: Today, I decided to switch the target device to an Android tablet. Am still having the same problem in that the video can not be stored or retrieved from the cache. Fortunately, with Android it's a fairly easy jump to use PhoneGap to turn it into a native app - so my money's on that for now. Interestingly, to get the cache to work on Android it seems that, in the cache.manifest file, after the "CACHE MANIFEST" line you need a "CACHE:" line. I haven't tried that on iOS, but maybe that line could help your video to be retrieved?

Comment: user1618024, how are you getting on? I came across this solution here - not sure if it will work (or is practical) for you but may be worth a try?... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270175/ios-did-apple-disable-html5-offline-capability-for-web-apps-saved-to-the-home-s

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat related issue with playing video on an iPad.  This was in an HTML widget that will reside in an iBooks file.  My problem was I couldn't get the videos to rewind, so when you went back to that screen the video was stuck at the end (or still playing if you went back fast enough.)

The workaround I came up with was to load a different video and then reload the video I wanted to play.  It's ugly, but it works, and it may provide a workaround for your problem.

```
var sources = videoEl.getElementsByTagName('source');
sources[0].src = "assets/TeethMouth_Anim_Part3_03.mp4"; // Load some other video into the source, in my case, a video that I'm playing later in the presentation.
videoEl.load();
sources[0].src = "assets/TeethMouth_Anim_Part1_03.mp4"; // Then reload the video I want to play.
videoEl.load();
```

Although now I see that this thread is a year old so it's probably not an issue anymore.  Still, thought I'd post it.